# checking target: expected to have shape (3404,) but got array with shape (1705,)

Tags: python-3.x, keras

In the following code i am getting an error regarding the shape. Unable to understand and looking for help while calling the fit() function

```py
import keras
from keras.models import Model, load_model,Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense

hidden_layer_len = 300
# X and Y are input and output respectively with shape (3404, 1705)

model = Sequential()
inputLayer = Dense(units= X.shape[0])
hiddenLayer = Dense(units=hidden_layer_len,activation='linear')
outputLayer = Dense(units=Y.shape[0],activation='softmax')

model.add(inputLayer)
model.add(hiddenLayer)
model.add(outputLayer)

model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(X,Y,epochs=50)
```

I am unable to understand why this error is coming.

Comment: What is the shape of X and Y (`print(X.shape, Y.shape)` should do it)? Usually the input and output shapes are `(samples, shape_1, shape_2, ...)` so your layers are shaped to the number of samples instead of the size of each sample.

Comment: My purpose with this code is to create the word2vec embeddings, without using the Embeddings layer. What i understand till now is that 'units' is a measure of number of inputs/samples. So inputLayer  has samples of X.shape[0], hiddenLayer has 16 neurons and outputLayer should be equal to size of output Y.

Comment: Is there any link where the keras layers are explained well ? I like Keras as it lets up create a model as we see it. No hassles of remembering any calculus.

Comment: The keras documentation has some explanation of the layers (https://keras.io/layers/core/) but probably not what you are looking for. I think your model may work as you want it to if you use `X.shape[1]` and `Y.shape[1]` as your first and last layer sizes.